# Extending Bounty

Tags: support, bounty, moderator

As most of you are aware, this *question about coolers* is generating some good discussion... however, I am wondering how I can extend the bounty time period.

Mostly because I will be traveling unexpectedly in the next week, and am afraid I won't be able to give the answers the judgmental scrutiny they deserve.

Is this something a moderator has authority to help with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, a bounty is stuck in time. I suggest you award it before you leave.